# Can't install php 5.4

Tags: php

How can l install php 5.4 instead of php 5.6 in ubuntu 15.10? Is it possible to make it without phpbrew?
I found this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5
```

but as far i know it's not working since ubuntu 13.10

Comment: why do you want php5.4 ?

Comment: it used in my project

Comment: @Torondor PHP 5.6 can perfectly run code you wrote for 5.4. With extremely tiny exceptions.

Comment: Okay the above Answer works: I just don't have enough "reputation points" to put the damn response there. Few tips:
1.) You have to compile Apache httpd as well as pcre before compiling php.
2.) The default www Dir of Apache is /usr/local/apache2/htdocs as it's a UNIX install on Ubuntu so little different. I am running: Maui 1 Aurora (Ubuntu 16.x.x variant) hope this helps.

Comment: PHP 5.6 can do all the tasks needed for 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finding a supported PPA or DEB is usually the best route, but as a last resort, I used to have moderate success compiling PHP from source.

Sourcecode:
http://php.net/downloads.php#v5.4.45

Detailed Official Instructions:
http://php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php

```
cd ../php-NN
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php54 --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-mysql
make
make install
```

etc.  You need the apache2-dev package to link the source.

By using --prefix=, you can have multiple versions of PHP installed at once.